# So how do I log out now?

Tags: support, top-bar, login

First, I should mention that I'm very old. As in I was taught that $1$ is a prime number. So I get annoyed when things change, even if it's for the better.

So now (October 9, 2017, if I recall correctly) they've redesigned math.SE so that it's more consistent with other StackExchange sites.

And now I have no idea how to log out.

This wouldn't be a big deal if I was logging in from my home computer (that one doesn't connect to the Internet, long story). Here at the university library they take that thing that kind of seriously.

Normally I look at "Questions that may already have your answer" but today those have been singularly unhelpful.

Comment: Top right corner of the page, if you press the icon which says "list of all 171 stackexchange sites", then there is a log off option there.

Comment: @JohnDoe Oh yes, there it is! Thank you very much.

Comment: Alright, logging out now, thanks.

Comment: Tangentially, if you use it in a library, it could make sense to use if possible a private browsing window.  You can then just close that.

Comment: You're not older than GH Hardy, are you? He seemed to think that 1 was not prime. :)

Comment: @MarkMcClure But Hardy was a professional mathematician. Phil Farrand, George Will and Mr. Brooks here are not. Maybe I should also include Carl Sagan in that list...

Comment: But to get back on topic, and for what it's worth, I like the redesign and it caused me only a very brief disorientation.

Comment: Just click *StackExchange* on the top left corner of the page :)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Pretty much the same as before. Only the button moved to a new location.

In the top bar, it is the right-most button, with the icon that looks like the SE logo. Clicking on it will open a menu which tells you which site you are on, and what are your communities, and what are the available sites.

There you can choose to log out, again, as the right-most option.

[image]

Comment: So logging out is a far-right activity...

Comment: Well. Breitbart had a story about it last week...

Comment: Thanks! When you hover over that icon, it says "A list of all 171 stackexchange sites". Pretty non-intuitive that the logout button would be hidden there.